# how can i delete an entry from Dictionary data structure in Typescript based on the key?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary

I am using a dictionary data structure,where Key is the Id and value is PersonInformation,

```
interface PersonInformation{
FirstName:string;
SecondName:string;
Age:string;
}
```

How can i delete an entry of a person from the Dictionary,based on the Id.

Comment: delete dictionary[id];

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if your dictionary is an `object` you can delete an object property like this:

```
// in case your dictionary is object:
const Dictionary = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
}

delete Dictionary['firstname']; // <-- Use your ID instead

console.log(Dictionary.firstname);
// expected output: undefined
```

```
// As in your comments you said your dictionary is like following:
//in case your dictionary is an Array
const Dictionary = [ ]; 
Dictionary.push({ key: PersonId , value: PersonDescription })

//in this case you can do this:

const newDictionary = Dictionary.filter(item => item.key !== id)
// newDictionary is an Array without the item with key === id
```

check this link in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgS2FB4CGAnAnjAvDAbRgF0BuGAKEWVTEywDoAHAVwgAsAKAbxgGsAplgBcMAOQIAJgEYxMADQwAbmgA2LAaLEr1A2TAC%20ASipIU6bMzZdegkeKkAmOYp0atbgc8Mnq5upasHDz8QlpSAMwuymru4p5RPhQA9MkIYDBQ7AgQMMBoEAIwWCAseWgZkiCZ2RDCFKCQsIWqAsgCkgCSkgAqIHACrVBF%20BKSzg3g0DBgAgDufrT0ePBmS5YAZgiqwxicCMMAtngAfDAHAocMdjAAhLj4LW3DXb39gwLDJpOQIK0MqhAAHNOLMFmsLFhvqkiLwAER2OGiOFSaRwxRwzxImCY2J6OGGRTwxHIyLonFY5EJAkGEhAA)

Comment: this is how i am writing my code...Dictionary = [ ];   Dictionary.push({
        key: PersonId,
        value: PersonDescription
    })    delete Dictionary[PersonId];       ...This is throwing an error because the implicit type of PersonId is any.

Comment: I've edited the answer so you can delete that way too

Comment: because ```Dictionary.filter``` returns a new array without the deleted item which you can use

Comment: added a playground link to the end of my answer , check it @Sakshi